# JSON Assertions in CA LISA

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, json

Has anybody tried scripting json response assertions in CA LISA Tool.
All I could find was string match where I was giving "key":" value" exactly to ensure the presence of that combination in my web service response. But sometimes, there might be multiple same "key":" values" in my response and this may not be an ideal way to match.

I am looking for some help with scripted assertions where I can check something like "key[1]":" value" matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find much info about the CA Lisa tool, but if it uses a programming language then most have [a JSON parsing library](http://json.org/) to make your life easier.

If not then you could write your own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063690/how-to-write-a-basic-json-parsing-class